# How can I find the path of converted CSV file in Flutter? (Sqlite to CSV)

Tags: sqlite, csv, flutter

I have a Sqflite table, and converted to csv file using this code.

**db.dart**

```
class DBHelper {
         
Future exportVoca() async {
    final db = await database;
    var result = await db.query('vocas');
    var csv = mapListToCsv(result);
    return csv;
  }
}
```

then, I tried to export the csv file with [esys fuller share plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share), and realized to find the path of csv file. How can I find the exact path of converted csv file? I also used [file_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker), but it doesn't work.

**share.dart**

```
Future<void> shareCSV() async {
    var year = DateFormat('yy').format(DateTime.now());
    var month = DateFormat('MM').format(DateTime.now());
    var day = DateFormat('d').format(DateTime.now());

    DBHelper sd = DBHelper();
    String filePath = await FilePicker.getFilePath(
        type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['csv']);
    this.filePath = filePath;
    await sd.exportVoca();

    try {
      final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('$filePath');
      await Share.file('dontForget', 'dontForget_$year$month$day.csv',
          bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'text/csv');
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I didn't know that I have to write new csv file with csv content. So here's changed code below.

**db.dart**

```
Future exportVoca() async {
    var year = DateFormat('yy').format(DateTime.now());
    var month = DateFormat('MM').format(DateTime.now());
    var day = DateFormat('d').format(DateTime.now());

    final db = await database;
    var result = await db.query('vocas');
    var csv = mapListToCsv(result);
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // get path local directory.
    final pathOfFile = await directory.path; 
    File file = File("$pathOfFile/dontForget_$year$month$day.csv");
    file.writeAsString(csv); //writing new csv file with converted csv content.
    print(csv);
  }
```

**share.dart**

```
 Future<void> shareCSV() async {
    var year = DateFormat('yy').format(DateTime.now());
    var month = DateFormat('MM').format(DateTime.now());
    var day = DateFormat('d').format(DateTime.now());

    DBHelper sd = DBHelper();
    await sd.exportVoca();

    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final pathOfFile = await directory.path;

    try {
      final ByteData bytes =
          await rootBundle.load('$pathOfFile/dontForget_$year$month$day.csv');
      await Share.file('dontForget', 'dontForget_$year$month$day.csv',
          bytes.buffer.asUint8List(), 'text/csv');
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }
```

**and finally, it works like charm.**

[image]